# Rewrite rule to globally omit subdirectory in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a site and currently it is like:

```
www.domain.com/forum/us
www.domain.com/forum/ca
www.domain.com/forum/mx
```

etc.

What we'd like the URL rewrite to do is to globally strip out "forum" such that anything added is www.domain.com/{country}. Such as:

```
www.domain.com/us(/)
www.domain.com/ca(/)
www.domain.com/mx(/)
```

Is there a way within Apache Rewrite rules to ignore a directory for the URL in such a blanket manner?

Comment: Do you already a .htaccess in `/forum/` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in /root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

#--Don't rewrite existent directries
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#--And files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#--Rewrite any other request to "/forum/"
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /forum/$1 [NC,L]
```